# Tar encounters “Cannot open: Not a directory” while compressing

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am using fakeroot v1.12.4 for packaging and extraction on **RHEL-6.4**. I have two different servers where I am compressing files using tar v1.23. Compression is failing on one server with this error:

```
tar: ./isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

If I check file type for this file (as a normal user), it says it is a ASCII file:

```
girishp@~$ file ./isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: ASCII English text
girishp@~$
```

But If I check file type in fakeroot environment, it says it is directory:

```
+ file ./isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
./isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: directory
```

The command I am using to compress is:

```
tar -czf /home/users/girishp/tarfiles/mytar.tgz .
```

Using `*` instead of `.`

```
tar -czf /home/users/girishp/tarfiles/mytar.tgz *
```

I compared environment variables of both machine, there is no difference in environment.  If I use `sudo` instead of `fakeroot`, it works fine. `strace` of `tar` says it is trying to open file with `O_DIRECTORY` option.

```
open("./isolinux/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
```

I tried to unset some environment variables used by `fakeroot`:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

Tar works fine with this.

Why does this file appear as a directory in fakeroot environment?

Comment: Do you mean it is problem with open() ?

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, but you output shiws a `Cannot open: NOT a directory`. So tar does not think it is a directory.  What happens if you try the same command with `*` rather than `.` ? Or in a clean shell?

Comment: It works fine in a clean shell as fakeroot is not used there. problem is only there when I perform tar in bash script spawned using fakeroot.
I didn't try with * as of now, I will share results once tested.

Comment: Sounds like you've found a bug in fakeroot. Which distro are you on? Which version of fakeroot?

Comment: Fakeroot version is 1.12.4 and distro is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago). updated same details

Comment: It's interesting that stat says it's a directory but opening itself says it's not. Again, this is a bug.

Comment: Btw unsetting LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH you are disabling fakeroot too.

Answer (score 0):

Updated fakeroot to v1.20.2-1, not facing issue with updated fakeroot.